# What is a correct loss for a model predicting angles from images?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, circular-statistics

### Backgrounds

I am working with a dataset, where compass-like images are labeled with their corresponding **angles from horizontal line** ($0$ degrees).

**I am trying to make a CNN model** to predict the correct label for each input observation. The following is my quick description of the data(train, with labels).

[image]

Note that labels have the coding scheme of describing the angle of the stick from the horizon as a real number between $0 \sim 179$ in degrees.

Since **angles $\pm 180 n$** for $n=1,2,\cdots$ have exactly the same meanings, the range $0 \sim 179$ was taken in order to make one-to-one correspondence to the picture and angle. For example, the first observation above could have been labeled as $-90, 90, 270, \cdots$ but in order to evade redundancy the range $0 \sim 179$ was taken.

---

### Try 1

I have made a vanilla CNN model using `Keras`, with the loss : **mean_squared_error**.

But I think this loss is very inappropriate, since it gives preference to angle $90$, whereas it gives disadvantages to angles $1$ or $179$. To support my argument, let me show you an example:

- For angle $90$, the model's try of $88$ or $92$ are both "close tries".
- For angle $179$, the model's try of $177$ are considered **close**, whereas $181$ is considered absurd. Therefore,

So I think this scheme should be evaded.

---

### Try 2

I have defined the following **sine loss**

$$
l(y_{true},y_{pred}) = \sin\left((y_{true}-y_{pred}) \times \frac{\pi}{180}\right)
$$

or in `Python` code using `Keras`, I have defined the following custom loss:

```
def sine_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    res = K.sin((y_true-y_pred)*np.pi/180.) 
    return(K.sum(res*res) )
```

I have trained the model using the above loss, and cross-validated using 180 angle samples. The result is as follows, where x axis is the ground-truth angle, and y axis is the predicted angle.

[image]

It was kind of frustrating to see that the range of predicted values, and I have tried to convert them into $0\sim 179$ space, using the above angle$\pm 180 n$ scheme, but there was a massive white noise.

---

What loss should I proceed in this situation?

Comment: people typically parameterize the target as $\sin(\theta), \cos(\theta)$.

Comment: Hi @moreblue, I am currently to perform pretty much the same task but on experimental data (charge stability diagrams of quantum dots). My model works fine on binary image (0, 1) generated by hand, but struggles learning anything with experimental data (it returns a value that minimize the loss, but it's the same for all images). What network architecture did you use in your problem? Funnily enough I also calculated the angles like you did ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can probably be done in a hand crafted way. No reason to use CNNs. If you do then why don't you pass your second last fully connected layer in to decision tree.

Otherwise the problem you are facing is that linear functions are not bounded. So use sigmoid activation on fully connected layers till the last one. If you are facing issue around 180 degrees, i would oversample such cases in the train set so network learns this very strongly

Answer (score 0):

On a simple regression task with lines on binary image, the MSE is enough to obtain very accurate results:

[image]

But adding noises, by generating the patches with a normal distribution for the background, I found that the `SmoothL1Loss` was a much better choice. I used [Pytorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.SmoothL1Loss.html#torch.nn.SmoothL1Loss) for that but you might have the same for [Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44130871/keras-smooth-l1-loss). It's not as precised as binary images but it works fine for the moment, it's a matter of tweating hyper-parameters and network size.

[image]

*The angles are sometimes not exact because of the anti alias used to generate the lines.*

[image]